# CAN Tx messages on STM32F4

Tags: stm32, can-bus

i m trying to write a simple code following the STM32 user manual.
Even if really really simple, I'm not able to see anything transmitted on CAN.
In DEBUG MODE after some cycles the mailboxes freelevel is 0 and there are some messages pending.
The error on hcan1 is CAN ERROR PARAM 0x200000.

Thank you in advance

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2023 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "cmsis_os.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;

CAN_HandleTypeDef hcan1;
CAN_HandleTypeDef hcan2;

I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c2;

SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;
SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi2;
SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi4;
SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi5;
SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi6;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

/* Definitions for defaultTask */
osThreadId_t defaultTaskHandle;
const osThreadAttr_t defaultTask_attributes = {
  .name = "defaultTask",
  .stack_size = 128 * 4,
  .priority = (osPriority_t) osPriorityNormal,
};
/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void);
static void MX_CAN1_Init(void);
static void MX_CAN2_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI2_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI4_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI5_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI6_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C2_Init(void);
void StartDefaultTask(void *argument);

/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_CAN1_Init();
  MX_CAN2_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  MX_SPI2_Init();
  MX_SPI4_Init();
  MX_SPI5_Init();
  MX_SPI6_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_I2C2_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  HAL_CAN_Start(&hcan1);


  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Init scheduler */
  osKernelInitialize();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_MUTEX */
  /* add mutexes, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_MUTEX */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_SEMAPHORES */
  /* add semaphores, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_SEMAPHORES */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_TIMERS */
  /* start timers, add new ones, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_TIMERS */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_QUEUES */
  /* add queues, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_QUEUES */

  /* Create the thread(s) */
  /* creation of defaultTask */

  defaultTaskHandle = osThreadNew(StartDefaultTask, NULL, &defaultTask_attributes);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_THREADS */
  /* add threads, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_THREADS */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_EVENTS */
  /* add events, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_EVENTS */

  /* Start scheduler */
  osKernelStart();
  /* We should never get here as control is now taken by the scheduler */
  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */


  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 180;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 4;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Activate the Over-Drive mode
  */
  if (HAL_PWREx_EnableOverDrive() != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_5) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief ADC1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 0 */

  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 1 */

  /** Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion)
  */
  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV8;
  hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1;
  hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_0;
  sConfig.Rank = 1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_3CYCLES;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief CAN1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_CAN1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END CAN1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END CAN1_Init 1 */
  hcan1.Instance = CAN1;
  hcan1.Init.Prescaler = 10;
  hcan1.Init.Mode = CAN_MODE_NORMAL;
  hcan1.Init.SyncJumpWidth = CAN_SJW_1TQ;
  hcan1.Init.TimeSeg1 = CAN_BS1_15TQ;
  hcan1.Init.TimeSeg2 = CAN_BS2_2TQ;
  hcan1.Init.TimeTriggeredMode = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.AutoBusOff = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.AutoWakeUp = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.AutoRetransmission = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.ReceiveFifoLocked = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.TransmitFifoPriority = DISABLE;
  if (HAL_CAN_Init(&hcan1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_Init 2 */
  if(HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&hcan1,CAN_FILTER_FIFO0) != HAL_OK) Error_Handler();
  /* USER CODE END CAN1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief CAN2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_CAN2_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END CAN2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END CAN2_Init 1 */
  hcan2.Instance = CAN2;
  hcan2.Init.Prescaler = 10;
  hcan2.Init.Mode = CAN_MODE_NORMAL;
  hcan2.Init.SyncJumpWidth = CAN_SJW_1TQ;
  hcan2.Init.TimeSeg1 = CAN_BS1_15TQ;
  hcan2.Init.TimeSeg2 = CAN_BS2_2TQ;
  hcan2.Init.TimeTriggeredMode = DISABLE;
  hcan2.Init.AutoBusOff = DISABLE;
  hcan2.Init.AutoWakeUp = DISABLE;
  hcan2.Init.AutoRetransmission = DISABLE;
  hcan2.Init.ReceiveFifoLocked = DISABLE;
  hcan2.Init.TransmitFifoPriority = DISABLE;
  if (HAL_CAN_Init(&hcan2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN2_Init 2 */
  if(HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&hcan2,CAN_FILTER_FIFO0) != HAL_OK) Error_Handler();
  /* USER CODE END CAN2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief I2C2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_I2C2_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C2_Init 1 */
  hi2c2.Instance = I2C2;
  hi2c2.Init.ClockSpeed = 100000;
  hi2c2.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2;
  hi2c2.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
  hi2c2.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c2.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c2.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c2.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c2.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure Analogue filter
  */
  if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigAnalogFilter(&hi2c2, I2C_ANALOGFILTER_ENABLE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure Digital filter
  */
  if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigDigitalFilter(&hi2c2, 0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief SPI1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 1 */
  /* SPI1 parameter configuration*/
  hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_HARD_OUTPUT;
  hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief SPI2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_SPI2_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI2_Init 1 */
  /* SPI2 parameter configuration*/
  hspi2.Instance = SPI2;
  hspi2.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi2.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi2.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi2.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi2.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi2.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_HARD_OUTPUT;
  hspi2.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2;
  hspi2.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi2.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi2.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi2.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief SPI4 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_SPI4_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI4_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI4_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI4_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI4_Init 1 */
  /* SPI4 parameter configuration*/
  hspi4.Instance = SPI4;
  hspi4.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi4.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi4.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi4.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi4.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi4.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_HARD_OUTPUT;
  hspi4.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2;
  hspi4.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi4.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi4.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi4.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI4_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI4_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief SPI5 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_SPI5_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI5_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI5_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI5_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI5_Init 1 */
  /* SPI5 parameter configuration*/
  hspi5.Instance = SPI5;
  hspi5.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi5.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi5.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi5.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi5.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi5.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_HARD_OUTPUT;
  hspi5.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2;
  hspi5.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi5.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi5.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi5.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi5) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI5_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI5_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief SPI6 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_SPI6_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI6_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI6_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI6_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI6_Init 1 */
  /* SPI6 parameter configuration*/
  hspi6.Instance = SPI6;
  hspi6.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi6.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi6.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi6.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi6.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi6.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_HARD_OUTPUT;
  hspi6.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2;
  hspi6.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi6.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi6.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi6.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi6) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI6_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI6_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief USART1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 1 */
  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_RTS_CTS;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief USART2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_1 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_1 */

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOG_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, IsoSPI1_DIS_Pin|OUT4_DEN_Pin|LOCK_CMD_Pin|LOCK_DEN_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOF, SAFETY_RESET_Pin|PROXIMITY_EXC_Pin|IsoSPI2_DIS_Pin|IsoSPI2_BNE_Pin
                          |OUT1_CMD_Pin|OUT1_DEN_Pin|OUT2_CMD_Pin|OUT2_DEN_Pin
                          |OUT3_CMD_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOG, OUT3_DEN_Pin|OUT4_CMD_Pin|AVDC_ENABLE_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, EEPROM_HOLD_Pin|EEPROM_WP_Pin|GNSS_RESET_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, CAN3_ENABLE_Pin|CAN2_ENABLE_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CAN3_RESET_GPIO_Port, CAN3_RESET_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, INTERLOCK_CONTROL_Pin|CP_PE_SWITCH_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LTE_RESET_GPIO_Port, LTE_RESET_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LTE_PWR_ON_GPIO_Port, LTE_PWR_ON_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CAN1_ENABLE_GPIO_Port, CAN1_ENABLE_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(PLC_RESET_GPIO_Port, PLC_RESET_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : IsoSPI1_DIS_Pin OUT4_DEN_Pin LOCK_CMD_Pin LOCK_DEN_Pin
                           EEPROM_HOLD_Pin EEPROM_WP_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = IsoSPI1_DIS_Pin|OUT4_DEN_Pin|LOCK_CMD_Pin|LOCK_DEN_Pin
                          |EEPROM_HOLD_Pin|EEPROM_WP_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : IsoSPI1_BNE_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = IsoSPI1_BNE_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(IsoSPI1_BNE_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : SAFETY_RESET_Pin PROXIMITY_EXC_Pin IsoSPI2_DIS_Pin IsoSPI2_BNE_Pin
                           OUT1_CMD_Pin OUT1_DEN_Pin OUT2_CMD_Pin OUT2_DEN_Pin
                           OUT3_CMD_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = SAFETY_RESET_Pin|PROXIMITY_EXC_Pin|IsoSPI2_DIS_Pin|IsoSPI2_BNE_Pin
                          |OUT1_CMD_Pin|OUT1_DEN_Pin|OUT2_CMD_Pin|OUT2_DEN_Pin
                          |OUT3_CMD_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOF, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : OUT3_DEN_Pin OUT4_CMD_Pin AVDC_ENABLE_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = OUT3_DEN_Pin|OUT4_CMD_Pin|AVDC_ENABLE_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOG, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : GNSS_RESET_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GNSS_RESET_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_OD;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GNSS_RESET_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : CAN3_ENABLE_Pin CAN2_ENABLE_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = CAN3_ENABLE_Pin|CAN2_ENABLE_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : IGNITION_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = IGNITION_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(IGNITION_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : CAN3_INT_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = CAN3_INT_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_FALLING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(CAN3_INT_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : CAN3_RESET_Pin INTERLOCK_CONTROL_Pin CP_PE_SWITCH_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = CAN3_RESET_Pin|INTERLOCK_CONTROL_Pin|CP_PE_SWITCH_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : LOCK_FEEDBACK_Pin SPI6_TX_PENDING_Pin SPI6_RX_READY_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LOCK_FEEDBACK_Pin|SPI6_TX_PENDING_Pin|SPI6_RX_READY_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOG, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : LTE_RESET_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LTE_RESET_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_OD;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(LTE_RESET_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : LTE_PWR_ON_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LTE_PWR_ON_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_OD;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(LTE_PWR_ON_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : CAN1_ENABLE_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = CAN1_ENABLE_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(CAN1_ENABLE_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PLC_RESET_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = PLC_RESET_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_OD;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(PLC_RESET_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/* USER CODE BEGIN Header_StartDefaultTask */
/**
  * @brief  Function implementing the defaultTask thread.
  * @param  argument: Not used
  * @retval None
  */
/* USER CODE END Header_StartDefaultTask */
void StartDefaultTask(void *argument)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 5 */
  /* Infinite loop */
    CAN_TxHeaderTypeDef   TxHeader;

      uint8_t               TxData[8];

      uint32_t              TxMailbox;

  for(;;)
  {
          TxHeader.IDE = CAN_ID_STD;
          TxHeader.StdId = 0x446;
          TxHeader.RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;
          TxHeader.DLC = 2;


          TxData[0] = 50;
          TxData[1] = 0xAA;

          uint32_t freelevel =HAL_CAN_GetTxMailboxesFreeLevel(&hcan1);

          if (HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan1, &TxHeader, TxData, &TxMailbox) != HAL_OK)
          {
             Error_Handler ();
          }
         uint32_t messagepending =HAL_CAN_IsTxMessagePending(&hcan1,TxMailbox);

    osDelay(1);
  }
  /* USER CODE END 5 */
}

/**
  * @brief  Period elapsed callback in non blocking mode
  * @note   This function is called  when TIM6 interrupt took place, inside
  * HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(). It makes a direct call to HAL_IncTick() to increment
  * a global variable "uwTick" used as application time base.
  * @param  htim : TIM handle
  * @retval None
  */
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Callback 0 */

  /* USER CODE END Callback 0 */
  if (htim->Instance == TIM6) {
    HAL_IncTick();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Callback 1 */

  /* USER CODE END Callback 1 */
}

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

In DEBUG MODE after some cycles the mailboxes freelevel is 0 and there are some messages pending.
The error on hcan1 is CAN ERROR PARAM 0x200000

Comment: What simple code you are trying to write which requires of initialising 6 SPIs, 2 Can buses, 2 UARTs, 1 I2C, 1 ADC and 7 GPIO ports (probably including some that doesn't exist on your chip)? The error caused by conflict in configuration parameters in your configuration. First thing to learn about STM32 programming before writing any code is how to configure the chip. Configure only the peripheral you require...

Comment: thank you, the problem was that the hardware needed to be enabled setting a gpio to high. now it works.

Answer (score 0):

thank you, the problem was that the hardware transceiver needed to be enabled setting a gpio to high. now it works.